# What happens in STL<vector> when an element is removed from between?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, stl

Since the memory locations are contiguous for stl vector are rest of elements moved back by one step? How did the stl library writers implement it?

Comment: Third paragraph in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

Comment: This question probably has different answers for C++03 and C++11, as moving is an obvious C++11 solution not available in C++03.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All following elements are moved one step back. Vector guarantees to hold its elements in continuous block of memory, so no internal holes are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the elements following the erased element are shifted by one position. This is the only way it can be implemented under the guarantees provided by `std::vector`.

Comment: @srinivasprabhu (1) it isn't specified how an implementation does this, however, (2) it's highly unrealistic that an implementation might do this more efficient while still holding to the specification of `std::vector`.

Comment: @srinivasprabhu: There is any number of reasons why the interviewer might have said that, including: (1) ignorance; (2) an attempt to confuse you.

Comment: (2) seems more probable :P

Comment: @srinivasprabhu I don't know.  I've seen some pretty incompetent people doing interviews.  As leemes says, there really isn't any other way to do this.

Comment: I guess Loading all the next elements(after deleted element) into shared memory first and then synchronising till the load finishes and then copying them parallely could be one of the options !! Any one has any opinions on this ??